# $A\geq B\Rightarrow A^{-1}\leq B^{-1}$ entrywise for pos.def. symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

My question follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857976/inverse-inequality-of-symmetric-matrix. Suppose we assume that $A$ and $B$ are two positive definite matrices with positive entries and $A\geq B $ entry wise.
Can we say that $A^{-1}\leq B^{-1}$ entry wise? 
I tried with numeric examples in Matlab, but I am not getting any counter-example.
Any help would be really great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{10} \\
 \frac{1}{10} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;A^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{100}{99} & -\frac{10}{99} \\
 -\frac{10}{99} & \frac{100}{99} \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=B^{-1}$$
is a counter example.

Comment: Can I take the liberty to ask you here itself, will the inequality hold true if we put any more conditions on A? Even a hint would be enough.

Comment: sorry, no idea why this inequality should hold in some general sense.

Comment: Slightly more generally, suppose $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ positive definite symmetric matrix.  The partial derivative of $(A^{-1})_{1,1}$ with respect to the entry $a_{1,2}$ is $2 a_{12} a_{22}/(\det A)^2$.  Thus if $a_{12} > 0$, increasing $a_{12}$ (and keeping $a_{21}=a_{12}$) increases $(A^{-1})_{11}$ rather than decreasing it.